# How to open a .html file in a smartphone

Tags: c#, html, file-io, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

i have a C# program written on visual studios 2008 windows mobile 6. I want to open a html file in the path @"\My Documents\maptoolkit.html" and after that it will open the mini-opera browser display whatever's necessary. It is by default the mini-opera browser if i opened it directly. 
 How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Process.Start(@"\My Documents\maptoolkit.html", "");
```

Comment: Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' C:\Users\TP1234\Desktop\Andrew\Important\Snap2PlayV.01\Snap2PlayV.01\GameMenu.cs 98 27 Snap2PlayV.01

Comment: yea this is the error. Even before you gave the suggestion, i tried it before doesn't work

Comment: @cheesebunz: Pass an empty string as the second parameter.  (See my edit)